# Nullspace of  combination of two basis vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-algebra

I have two 6x1 element basis vectors $s_1$ and $s_2$ defined in local coordinates which can be combined into a single 6x2 subspace of $$ s = \begin{vmatrix}
X_{2}s_{1} & s_{2}\end{vmatrix}$$ where $X_2$ is a 6x6 affine transformation matrix.

If I know the individual 6x5 *nullspaces* $R_1 = {\rm null}(s_1^\top)$ and $R_2 = {\rm null}(s_2^\top)$ such that $s_1^\top R_1 = 0$ and $s_2^\top R_2 = 0$ how do I calculate the combined 6x4 nullspace $R={\rm null}(s^\top)$ from $R_1$ and $R_2$ ?

**Example**

A joint is described by the rotation $s_1^\top = \begin{vmatrix} 0&0&0&0&0&1 \end{vmatrix}$ followed by the translation $s_2^\top = \begin{vmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0 \end{vmatrix}$ with the affine transformation $$ X_{2}=\begin{vmatrix}1 &  &  & 0 & -z & y\\
 & 1 &  & z & 0  & -x\\
 &  & 1 & -y & x & 0\\
 &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  &  &  & 1
\end{vmatrix} $$

Combined this gives $$ s = \begin{vmatrix}-y & 1\\
x & 0\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{vmatrix} $$

The computed nullspace with Matlab(r) is
$$ R = {\rm null}(s^\top)=\begin{vmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x}\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} $$

The question is how do I arrive at this algorithmically or analytically?

Comment: $R$ is the nullspace basis of which matrix?

Comment: $R$ is ${\rm null}(s^\top)$

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem I came up with, goes as follows:

Partition the subspace $s$ into a `m×m` part $s_m$ (where `m` is the number of columns in $s$) and into a `k×m` remaining part $s_k$

$$ s = \begin{vmatrix} s_m \\ \hline s_k  \end{vmatrix} $$

The nullspace transpose is $$R = \begin{vmatrix} -\left(s_k s_m^{-1}\right)^\top \\ \hline \left(1_{k\times k}\right)  \end{vmatrix} $$

### Example

For the example above with

$$ s = \begin{vmatrix} -y & 1 \\ x & 0 \\ \hline 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 \\0 & 0 \\1 &0  \end{vmatrix} $$

the nullspace transpose is

$$ R = \begin{vmatrix}
 -\left(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 \\0 & 0 \\1 &0   \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -y & 1 \\ x & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}  \right)^\top
  \\ \hline \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &1 \end{pmatrix} \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{x} \end{pmatrix} \\ \hline \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &1 \end{pmatrix} \end{vmatrix} $$

### Why?

Expanding $R^\top s =0$ we have

$$\begin{vmatrix} -\left(s_k s_m^{-1}\right)^\top \\ \hline \left(1_{k\times k}\right)  \end{vmatrix}^\top  \begin{vmatrix} s_m \\ \hline s_k  \end{vmatrix} =0 $$

$$ -\left( s_k s_m^{-1} \right) s_m + s_k = \\
     -(s_k ) + s_k = 0 $$

So $R$ is the nullspace transpose of $s$.